# Use clamshell mode without power adapter

Tags: macos, display, closed-clamshell

One of the requirements to use [clamshell mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) is to have the power adapter plugged in.  Is their any file modification or app that will work around this?  Like to switch throughout the day from a sit down desk to stand up and bringing the power adapter back and forth, is becoming more of a hassle.

Comment: Clamshell works for me with or without power adapter... running 10.11.6 El Capitan

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not answer the question; stating that Clamshell mode works with/without power adapter does not help answer the question. Perhaps you could include the settings you have made, or anything that affects this outcome?

Comment: I didn't change anything at all, was just trying to say it works out of the box as intended for me...only reason I brought up clamshell with/without adapter is because that's what the title of the thread is; also mentioned in first post

Comment: Per the [Apple support link the OP provided](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834), Mac laptops _must_ be plugged in in order for "closed-display" or clamshell mode to work. The fact that you are stating it works differently means it is actually _not_ working as intended on your computer.

Comment: Oh well, I've never had any problems with it, this is something I use daily; thought it worked that way for everybody

Comment: Maybe it's because I hook up with both USB keyboard and mouse & effectively use my laptop as a desktop?http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/15/how-to-use-a-macbook-or-macbook-pro-with-the-lid-closed-and-hooked-to-an-external-monitor/

Comment: Closing the lid works for me... for about 30 seconds. Then it sleeps. The InsomniaX solution posted by @grgarside works for me. (Sierra 10.12.1.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [Insomniax](http://semaja2.net/projects/insomniaxinfo/) to disable sleep when the display is closed. This will mean that you can close the lid and display the screen on a secondary monitor mode without needing to have a power adapter connected as the Mac will not sleep when you close the lid.

---

Insomniax is now abandonware and no further updates or binaries will be supplied. [Further info](https://github.com/semaja2/InsomniaX).

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: On opening the link of Insomniax, it gives `Cannot GET /projects/insomniaxinfo/`

Answer (score 1):

An extension called [nosleep](https://github.com/integralpro/nosleep/releases) does exactly this. Free and easy to set up!

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE A SHORTCUT/APPLICATION TO TOGGLE BETWEEN SLEEP MODES**

Open 'Automator' create 'New Document' and choose 'Application', on the top left bar search and choose "run AppleScript".
Paste the commands below and save the file to desired location. Voila ! Double click to toggle the sleep settings,

Toggle off the sleep mode and use your macbook with clamshell closed.

*PS: it runs sudo commands hence it will ask for your credentials.*

*Hack: Run the Application once to disable the sleep mode , close the lid (clamshell mode) , run the application again to enable the sleep mode.You can now continue working in clamshell mode and can 'sleep' your macbook when you are done with your work.*

```
on run {input, parameters}
    do shell script "sleepvar=\"$(pmset -g | grep SleepDisabled)\"
       sleepval=\"$(grep -c 0 <<< $sleepvar)\"
       if [[ $sleepval -eq 1 ]];
          then 
            #echo \"SleepDisabled set to 0, setting to 1 i.e. Disabling sleep\"
            sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
          else
            #echo \"SleepDisabled set to 1, setting to 0 i.e. Enabling sleep\"
            sudo pmset -b sleep 1; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0
       fi" with administrator privileges    
    return input
end run
```

If you want to create a rather lightweight but a bit less UI friendly ***executable bash script, follow my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462513/501809)***